Finding unmatchable edges in a graph
Definition: An unmatchable edge is an edge that is not contained in any perfect matching of $G$.
Problem: Given a graph $G = (V, E)$, find all unmatchable edges of $G$.
Apparently this problem is solvable in $O(V^3)$ time. I was able to solve this problem for bipartite Graphs by finding a perfect matching $M$ in $G$, directing all matching edges in one direction and the rest in the other direction. Then the unmatchable edges are the edges that have endpoints in different strongly connected components. However, I don't see how I can generalize this algorithm to general graphs.

An edge that can be included in a maximum-cardinality matching is called a maximally matchable edge. The $O(VE)$-time algorithm [1] is the best known algorithm for this problem in general graphs. Alternatively, one can apply the randomized algebraic algorithm [2] [3].
For a simple graph $(V, E)$, let $A$ be the Tutte matrix with indeterminate variables $\{x_{i,j}\}_{i,j}$. Then, the determinant is non-zero if and only if the graph has a perfect matching. Moreover, assuming that $\mathrm{det}(A) \neq 0$, for $(i,j) \in E$, we have $A^{-1}_{j,i} \neq 0$ if and only if $(i,j)$ is a matchable edge [2]. By randomly assigning the indeterminate variables as Schwartz–Zippel lemma and explicitly computing the inverse matrix using the Gaussian elimination, we can determine all matchable edges in $O(V^3)$ time.

[1] Marcelo H De Carvalho, Joseph Cheriyan. "An O(VE) Algorithm for Ear Decompositions of Matching-Covered Graphs." ACM Transactions on Algorithms 1.2 (2005).
[2] Michael O Rabin, Vijay V Vazirani. "Maximum Matchings in General Graphs through Randomization." Journal of algorithms 10.4 (1989). https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~pettie/matching/Rabin-Vazirani-randomized-maximum-matching.pdf
[3] Marcin Mucha, Piotr Sankowski. "Maximum Matchings via Gaussian Elimination." 45th Annual IEEE Symposium on Foundations of Computer Science (2004). https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~mucha/pub/mucha_sankowski_focs04.pdf


Not in $\mathcal{O}(V^3)$, but you could, for each edge $e = \{u,v\}$, delete $u$ and $v$ and all edges with extremity $u$ or $v$ and check if there is a perfect matching. If there is none, $e$ is unmatchable.
This would result in a $\mathcal{O}(E^2\sqrt{V})$ algorithm to find all unmatchable edges using Micali and Vazirani's algorithm.
